# Inserting a new row to data frame for each group id

Tags: r

I've looked extensively on stack overflow for a solution, but have yet to find one that works for me.
I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
id    time    latitude    longitude
A     11:10   381746.0    6008345
A     11:11   381726.2    6008294
B     10:56   381703.0    6008214
B     10:57   381679.7    6008134
C     4:30    381654.4    6008083
C     4:31    381629.2    6008033
```

I would like to insert a new row at the END of each id. In this row, I would like 'id' and 'time' to be the same as the previous observation. I would like latitude and longitude to be '394681.4' and '6017550' (corresponding to the end location of all id's).

```
id    time    latitude    longitude
A     11:10   381746.0    6008345
A     11:11   381726.2    6008294
A     11:11   394681.4    6017550
B     10:56   381703.0    6008214
B     10:57   381679.7    6008134
B     10:57   394681.4    6017550
C     4:30    381654.4    6008083
C     4:31    381629.2    6008033
C     4:32    394681.4    6017550
```

Can anyone think of a solution? Dplyr or data table solutions preferred.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', get the last row with `tail`, assign the 'latitude' and 'longitude' with the new values, `rbind` with the original dataset and `order` by 'id'.

```
library(data.table)
rbind(setDT(df1), df1[, tail(.SD, 1) , by = id
        ][, c("latitude", "longitude") := .(394681.4,  6017550)
         ])[order(id)]
#    id  time latitude longitude
#1:  A 11:10 381746.0   6008345
#2:  A 11:11 381726.2   6008294
#3:  A 11:11 394681.4   6017550
#4:  B 10:56 381703.0   6008214
#5:  B 10:57 381679.7   6008134
#6:  B 10:57 394681.4   6017550
#7:  C  4:30 381654.4   6008083
#8:  C  4:31 381629.2   6008033
#9:  C  4:31 394681.4   6017550
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, with similar methodology

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(time = last(time)) %>%
   mutate(latitude = 394681.4, longitude = 6017550) %>% 
   bind_rows(df1, .) %>% 
   arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R solution using the split-apply-combine concept.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), 
                      function(x) rbind(x,
                         within(x[nrow(x),], {latitude <- 394681.4; longitude <- 6017550}))))
```

which returns

```
     id  time latitude longitude
A.1   A 11:10 381746.0   6008345
A.2   A 11:11 381726.2   6008294
A.21  A 11:11 394681.4   6017550
B.3   B 10:56 381703.0   6008214
B.4   B 10:57 381679.7   6008134
B.41  B 10:57 394681.4   6017550
C.5   C  4:30 381654.4   6008083
C.6   C  4:31 381629.2   6008033
C.61  C  4:31 394681.4   6017550
```

`split` breaks the data.frame into a list of data.frames, `lapply` `rbind`s the final row to each data.frame, and `do.call` `rbind`s the resulting list of data.frames. The final row of each data.frame is produced using `within` which returns a modified version of the data.frame it is given. `nrow` is used to select the final row. referencing @akrun's answer, `x[nrow(x),]` could be replaced with `tail(x, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr

```
   library(dplyr)

 # data:   
    df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("10:56", "10:57", "11:10", "11:11", "4:30", 
    "4:31"), class = "factor"), latitude = c(381746, 381726.2, 381703, 
    381679.7, 381654.4, 381629.2), longitude = c(6008345L, 6008294L, 
    6008214L, 6008134L, 6008083L, 6008033L)), .Names = c("id", "time", 
    "latitude", "longitude"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))

 # code: 

    df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
        do({ df <- . 
             last_row           <- df %>% slice(n())
             last_row$latitude  <- 394681.4
             last_row$longitude <- 6017550
             df                 <- bind_rows(df, last_row)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

dplyr method

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice_tail() %>%
   bind_rows(df1) %>% 
   arrange(id,time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `tidyverse` option would be a combination of `tidyr::complete` to add the rows and `tidyr::fill` to fill missings values in `time`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  tidyr::complete(id, latitude = 394681.4, longitude = 6017550) |> 
  select(id, time, everything()) |> 
  arrange(id, time) |> 
  tidyr::fill(time)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   id    time  latitude longitude
#>   <fct> <fct>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A     11:10  381746    6008345
#> 2 A     11:11  381726.   6008294
#> 3 A     11:11  394681.   6017550
#> 4 B     10:56  381703    6008214
#> 5 B     10:57  381680.   6008134
#> 6 B     10:57  394681.   6017550
#> 7 C     4:30   381654.   6008083
#> 8 C     4:31   381629.   6008033
#> 9 C     4:31   394681.   6017550
```